# Find all files within directory using "FindFirstFileA" - C

Tags: c, winapi

I am using the Windows API and would like to be able to search through a specified directory and return the names of any files that reside within it.

I've made a start at it however i've hit a brick wall as i'm unsure of how to go any further.

Here is my progress so far:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

void main()
{
 HANDLE fileHandle;
 WIN32_FIND_DATAA fileData;

 fileHandle = FindFirstFileA("*.txt", &fileData);

 if(fileHandle != INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
 {
  printf("%s \n", fileData.cFileName);
 }
}
```

Comment: There is a complete example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364418%28VS.85%29.aspx. If you intend to do Windows programming, learning how to use MSDN is a necessary skill.

Comment: I've already seen the MSDN documentation but as i'm slightly new to C i didn't feel comfortable with changing it from C++

Comment: The code I posted a link to is C code, as are all the examples that illustrate the use of the Win32 API - it's a C API.

Comment: My apologies, when I saw "The following C++ example shows you a minimal use of FindFirstFile." I assumed it wouldn't work.

Comment: @Jamie Yes, that is misleading - some intern at MS probably wanted to make himself feel important.

Comment: This puts me of using MSDN sometimes as even though I use it frequently errors like the one you mentioned make it difficult to distinguish what to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to call FindNextFile in a loop to find all the files. There's a full example [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365200%28VS.85%29.aspx), here are the interesting bits:

```
hFind = FindFirstFile(szDir, &ffd);

if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == hFind) 
   return dwError;

do
{
   printf("%s\n"), ffd.cFileName);
}
while (FindNextFile(hFind, &ffd) != 0);
```

Comment: I tried using the example given on MSDN but it seems to close as soon as it opens.

Comment: I managed to get a snippet of text from the console:

\Release\Exercise 2.exe <directory name>
Press any key to continue . . .


I've omitted the directories leading up to the .exe

Comment: It's telling you how to use the program. You need to supply a directory name as a command line parameter. Or instead, you can incorporate the code I posted into your program - just change the variable names to the ones you used, and you may need to use FindNextFileA instead of FindNextFile.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

void main()
{
    HANDLE fileHandle;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA ffd;
    LARGE_INTEGER szDir;
    WIN32_FIND_DATA fileData;
    fileHandle = FindFirstFile("C:\\Users\\rest_of_the_Address\\*", &ffd);

    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == fileHandle)
        printf("Invalid File Handle Value \n");

    do
    {
        printf("%s\n", ffd.cFileName);
    } while (FindNextFile(fileHandle, &ffd) != 0);
    system("pause");
}
```

You were missing some declarations, and had some syntax errors, fixed up here, and also, remember to check the [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365200(v=vs.85).aspx) documentation (here is a msdn example for the program)

Comment: Also, the '*' at the end is for displaying all the files within the specified directory